# How to create a trivially copyable delegate to member function

Tags: c++, delegates, function-pointers

I need to create a trivially copyable delegate that will be executed in the base class using *this* as object and any derived class can bind one of its methods to it. Below is the code I've came up with.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ParameterTypes>
class FDelegate
{
    class FDelegateDummyClass;

    using MethodType = ReturnType (FDelegateDummyClass::*)(ParameterTypes...);

    MethodType BoundMethod;

public:

    FDelegate()
        : BoundMethod(nullptr)
    {
    }

    template<typename ClassName>
    void Bind(ReturnType (ClassName::*Method)(ParameterTypes...))
    {
        BoundMethod = (MethodType&)(Method);
    }

    void Unbind()
    {
        BoundMethod = nullptr;
    }

    bool IsBound() const
    {
        return BoundMethod != nullptr;
    }

    template<typename ObjectType>
    ReturnType Execute(ObjectType* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters)
    {
        return ((FDelegateDummyClass*)Object->*BoundMethod)(Parameters...);
    }

    template<typename ObjectType>
    ReturnType ExecuteIfBound(ObjectType* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters)
    {
        if (IsBound())
        {
            return Execute<ObjectType>(Object, Parameters...);
        }
    }
};

class FSampleBase
{
protected:

    FDelegate<void, int> NotifyFooInvoked;

public:

    void Foo(int Value)
    {
        NotifyFooInvoked.ExecuteIfBound(this, Value);
    }
};

class FSampleDerived : public FSampleBase
{
    int SampleData;

public:

    FSampleDerived(int Data)
        : SampleData(Data)
    {
        NotifyFooInvoked.Bind(&FSampleDerived::OnFooInvoked);
    }

    void OnFooInvoked(int Value)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo Invoked: " << Value << " [Sample Data: " << SampleData << "]" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FSampleDerived FirstSample(11);
    FSampleDerived* SecondSample = (FSampleDerived*)std::malloc(sizeof(FSampleDerived));

    std::memcpy(SecondSample, &FirstSample, sizeof(FSampleDerived));

    FirstSample.Foo(1);
    SecondSample->Foo(2);

    std::free(SecondSample);

    return 0;
}
```

Code on *ideone*: https://ideone.com/UxkUPv

The code works as intended but my questions are:
**1.** Will this code work on every architecture? Does it comply with the standard?
**2.** Is there a better way to do this? Maybe I'm not seeing an obvious solution.

EDIT:

Final solution based on the answer provided by @imreal: https://ideone.com/nbNmg1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ParameterTypes>
class IDelegateBinding
{
public:

    virtual ReturnType Execute(void* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters) = 0;
};

template<typename ObjectType, typename ReturnType, typename... ParameterTypes>
class FDelegateBinding : public IDelegateBinding<ReturnType, ParameterTypes...>
{
    using MethodType = ReturnType (ObjectType::*)(ParameterTypes...);

    MethodType BoundMethod;

public:

    FDelegateBinding(MethodType Method)
        : BoundMethod(Method)
    {
    }

    virtual ReturnType Execute(void* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters) override
    {
        return (((ObjectType*)Object)->*BoundMethod)(Parameters...);
    }
};

template<typename ReturnType, typename... ParameterTypes>
class FDelegate
{
    using DummyDelegateBinding = FDelegateBinding<class FDummyClass, ReturnType, ParameterTypes...>;

    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(DummyDelegateBinding), alignof(DummyDelegateBinding)>::type Binding;

public:

    FDelegate()
    {
        std::memset(&Binding, 0, sizeof(Binding));
    }

    template<typename ClassName>
    void Bind(ReturnType (ClassName::*Method)(ParameterTypes...))
    {
        new (&Binding) FDelegateBinding<ClassName, ReturnType, ParameterTypes...>(Method);
    }

    void Unbind()
    {
        std::memset(Binding, 0, sizeof(Binding));
    }

    bool IsBound() const
    {
        return (void*&)Binding != nullptr;
    }

    template<typename ObjectType>
    ReturnType Execute(ObjectType* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters)
    {
        return ((IDelegateBinding<ReturnType, ParameterTypes...>&)Binding).Execute(Object, Parameters...);
    }

    template<typename ObjectType>
    ReturnType ExecuteIfBound(ObjectType* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters)
    {
        if (IsBound())
        {
            return Execute<ObjectType>(Object, Parameters...);
        }
    }
};

class FSampleBase
{
protected:

    FDelegate<void, int> NotifyFooInvoked;

public:

    void Foo(int Value)
    {
        NotifyFooInvoked.ExecuteIfBound(this, Value);
    }
};

class FSampleDerived : public FSampleBase
{
    int SampleData;

public:

    FSampleDerived(int Data)
        : SampleData(Data)
    {
        NotifyFooInvoked.Bind(&FSampleDerived::OnFooInvoked);
    }

    void OnFooInvoked(int Value)
    {
        std::cout << "Foo Invoked: " << Value << " [Sample Data: " << SampleData << "]" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FSampleDerived FirstSample(11);
    FSampleDerived* SecondSample = (FSampleDerived*)std::malloc(sizeof(FSampleDerived));

    std::memcpy(SecondSample, &FirstSample, sizeof(FSampleDerived));

    FirstSample.Foo(1);
    SecondSample->Foo(2);

    std::free(SecondSample);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::is_trivially_copyable` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable to check ?

Comment: @RichardCritten How would it help me? What would I check? I want to create a trivially copyable **delegate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting the pointer to member function of type `ReturnType (ClassName::*)(ParameterTypes...)` here:

```
BoundMethod = (MethodType&)(Method);
```

is unspecified (unless you convert `BoundMethod` back to a pointer of type `ReturnType (ClassName::*)(ParameterTypes...)` later on)

Relevant C++ Standard quote:
N4296

> **5.2.10-10** A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different
>   type “pointer to member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both object types.72 The
>   null member pointer value (4.11) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. **The
>   result of this conversion is unspecified**, except in the following cases:
>   **(10.1)** — converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer to member function
>   type and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.
>   **(10.2)** — converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of X of type T1” to the type “pointer to data
>   member of Y of type T2” (where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1)
>   and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.

To answer your questions:

1. No, invoking a pointer to member function pointer without the correct type eliminates important information needed at runtime, specially in the cases of multiple inheritance, virtual inheritance, virtual functions.
2. I don't think it is possible to keep correct type information without using type erasure which prevents you from having a trivially copyable class.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How about this then: [https://ideone.com/3Bh69S](https://ideone.com/3Bh69S)

Comment: @Ogniok That works, but you don't have to do the C-style cast. Simply write `virtual ReturnType Execute(ObjectType* Object, ParameterTypes... Parameters) override`. One more thing, look into aligned_storage for your `Binding` buffer, it might not be properly aligned. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage